# Flutter ListTile not aligning correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use ListTile to create a list of options inside my drawer, written like this:

```
ListTile(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 0, 0),
              leading: IconTheme(
                data: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
                child: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.diceD6),
              ),
              title: Text(
                'FREE ASSETS',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
                leading: IconTheme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
                  child: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.folderOpen),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'RESOURCE COLLECTION',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                )),
            ListTile(
                leading: IconTheme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
                  child: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.chalkboard),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'LESSONS',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                )),
            ListTile(
                leading: IconTheme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
                  child: new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidRectangleList),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'NEWSLETTER',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                )),
          ],
        ),
```

My issue is that the icons and text are not aligned with each other.

[image]

I have not added any padding or margins to the icon and I suspect its because its aligning it to the bottom however I am unsure. Is there a way for me to fix the alignment of the icons or text?

Thank you for the help!

Edit:
By adding horizontalTitleGap: 0 it reduces the space however they are still not aligned with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this line inside your **ListTile()** widget:

```
titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.center,
```

This would align the **leading**, **title**, **trailing** to the center.
i hope this helps